# How to show the same value in one row using group by

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help.
I want to show the same value in one row from mysql using PHP.

I have table

```
ID  Name
------------------
01  Juan
01  Ben
02  Pedro
02  Jose
```

Expect Ouput

```
ID  NAME
--------------------
01  Juan, Ben
02  Pedro, Jose
```

How to do it?

Comment: have you at least made an attempt?

Comment: Before posting a question, you should have done the proper research and made attempts to solve your issue yourself. Then, if you get stuck on something _specific_, come back and show us your attempt. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the column you want to be unique and use `group_concat()` to get a list of the names for each group

```
select id, group_concat(name separator ', ') as names
from your_table
group by id
```

Comment: In my opinion, low quality questions that contains absolutely zero attempts shouldn't be answered. The OP should at least show _some_ effort of trying to solve the issue them selves before asking.

Comment: Thanks man, but one thing in using group_cat() how to change the separator the comma and add some space because the output it is one word

Comment: Thanks @juergen d you save my time :)